# Use shared filter in Python without sharing state

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I'm using Python's logging library and I have implemented a filter-class that keeps track of records that are being emitted through a handler that stores the records on a file. The filter will return False if a record has been emitted before so that we are not alerted twice of the same event.

The problem arose when I added a second handler which sends the record using the HTTPHandler. The handlers should have the same filter logic, so I reused the filter. When the first handler saves the record, the filter then keeps track of this separately, so when the second handler comes around it will find the record and return False.

Is there a way for the filter to know which handler is sending the record so that I can differentiate between them or is there another way? I could create a duplicate filter class or subclass it, but that feels a bit wrong (don't repeat yourself and all that).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution to my own problem. I was creating the filter once (I'm using dictConfig). Originally it was like this

```
{
    "formatters": {"myformatter": "..."}
    "handlers": {
        "handlerA": {
            "class": "myapp.logging.HandlerA",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "myformatter",
            "filters": [
                "myfilter"
            ]
        }
        "handlerB": {
            "class": "myapp.logging.HandlerB",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "myformatter",
            "filters": [
                "myfilter"
            ]
        }
    },
    "filters": {
        "myfilter": {
            "()": "myapp.logging.MyFilter"
        }
    }
    "loggers": {
        "myapp": {
            "handlers": [
                "handlerA",
                "handlerB"
            ],
            "level": "INFO"
        }
    }
}
```

This causeed the `myfilter` instance to be created once and shared. Instead of reimplementing the class twice or the need to keep track of which handler is sending the record I created a new filter id linking to the same object, which of course created a new instance of the filter object which I in my example calld `myotherfilter`:

```
{
    "formatters": {"myformatter": "..."}
    "handlers": {
        "handlerA": {
            "class": "myapp.logging.HandlerA",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "myformatter",
            "filters": [
                "myfilter"
            ]
        }
        "handlerB": {
            "class": "myapp.logging.HandlerB",
            "level": "INFO",
            "formatter": "myformatter",
            "filters": [
                "myotherfilter"
            ]
        }
    },
    "filters": {
        "myfilter": {
            "()": "myapp.logging.MyFilter"
        },
        "myotherfilter": {
            "()": "myapp.logging.MyFilter"
        }
    }
    "loggers": {
        "myapp": {
            "handlers": [
                "handlerA",
                "handlerB"
            ],
            "level": "INFO"
        }
    }
}
```